# What star domain has a non-star-domain interior?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Definition:** We call a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a *star domain* (or *star-shaped*) if there exists a point $x_0 \in S$ such that for every $x \in S$, the line segment $\overline{x_0x}$ is contained in $S$.

The [Wikipedia page on star domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) claims that

> The closure of a star domain is a star domain, but the interior of a star domain is not necessarily a star domain.

I must be particularly unimaginative, as I find myself unable to come up with an example of a star domain whose interior is not a star domain. What is such an example?

Comment: Silly example: A line segment in $\Bbb R^2$. Here the interior is empty! Use this idea to get a counterexample with nonempty interior. (Let the star point be somewhere not in the interior...)

Comment: Would a Singleton set satisfy?

Comment: Consider $S:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|y|\leq|x|\}$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For example, $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy\ge 0\}$ (that is, the first and third quadrant of the plane, plus the coordinate axes). This is a star-domain with star center $(0,0)$, but its interior is not even connected, and so cannot be a star-domain.

---

Whenever the original star-domain has an interior point as star-center, its interior will still be a star-domain: Assume without loss of generality that $x_0=0$, and suppose that $x$ is an interior point of $S$. Then it has a neighborhood entirely in $S$. For every $t\in (0,1]$ we can scale this entire neighborhood by a factor of $t$ get a neighborhood of $tx$ which must be entirely in $S$ due to the star-domain property. So we know that every point on $\overline{x_0x}$ must be in the interior of $S$, *except* possibly $x_0$ itself. Thus, if only $x_0$ is an interior point, then it will work as a star-center for the interior of $S$ too.

On the other hand, this is not a necessary condition: There are some star-domains whose *only* star-center is a boundary point, but whose interior is nevertheless a star-domain -- for example, the union of the two coordinate axes and *one* of the quadrants of the plane.